# Dynamics NAV Merging Objects after CU

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav

I am currently working on getting the Cumulative Update no.22 release for Italy(Dynamics NAV 2017).

My previous version was on CU7.

I am currently looking to update my objects but when i import the .fob file of the update i get warnings, many warnings , since my database is modified.

So after lot of research i found out that i can use Merge-NAVApplicationObject command to merge my objects and apply updates to them.

BUT i can not understand what paramaters should i set. Documentation says three parameters (Original , Target, Modified)

How am i supposed to know who is who? I have already updated my platform now looking to update my application objects.

Anyone done that before?

Answer (score 0):

Original is CU 7 without your modifications.

Target is CU 22

Modified is your solution.